# Forward search with okular: how to outline searched paragraph?

Tags: lyx, forward-inverse-search, vim-latex, okular

I have correctly configured forward search both for dvi (with xdvi) and pdf (with okular).
It works fine both within lyx and within vim-latex.

Yet there is a difference between dvi and pdf: if I perform forward search using dvi, the current paragraph is highlighted in the dvi. 
The same doesn't apply if I perform forward search using pdf.

This is a little annoying and my question is: is this the normal behavior (i.e., that feature is not available in okular)?
If not, what am I missing?

If needed for an answer, the commands I use in vim-latex to perform forward search are

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --synctex=1 interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*' 
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf =  'okular --unique 2>/dev/null 1>&2 '
```

Comment: This works for me (the corresponding paragraph in LyX is highlighted) on Ubuntu with LyX 2.3.0. What is your LyX version (please always provide this information in future posts)? I think there might have been some fixes for this feature in 2.3.0, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 with Lyx 2.2.3 (2.30 is not yet officially out). But the problem holds with vimlatex either. Maybe the problem is more on okular side: which version of okular do you have? Mine is 0.24.2

Comment: Sorry, I did not read correctly. It does not work for me. It is reverse-search that works for me (LyX highlights the location). As for forward search, Okular also does not highlight the paragraph for me, for both PDF and DVI (note that Okular can read DVIs). I have the same Okular version as you, 0.24.2. I'm guessing this is a missing feature in Okular, but that really is just a guess. Let us know if you get more information.